# Free memory allocated by Bitmap in ICS with Custom View

Tags: android, c++, memory, memory-management, bitmap

1.I am using a Custom View.

2.This Custom View I have implemented with my Activity.

3.I am Finishing my activity and recreating multiple time.

1. So it is  reallocating memory for Bitmap creation.
2. How can  I make sure that I am not reallocating a new memory every time .
3. How can I reuse or free the already allocated memory for Bitmap.

I want to get rid of **memory leak due to Bitmap**.

```
if (cachedBitmap == null){
  cachedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(),getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
  cachedCanvas = new Canvas(cachedBitmap);
  transparentColor = new int[cachedBitmap.getWidth()*cachedBitmap.getHeight()];

  for(int i = 0 ; i < (int) 5 *1.5 * cachedBitmap.getHeight() ; i++) {
     transparentColor[i]  = Color.TRANSPARENT;
  }
}

drawStuff(cachedCanvas);  
canvas.drawBitmap(cachedBitmap, 0, 0, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

In older versions of Android, Bitmap's are a native object instead of residing inside the Dalvik VM. This can be a problem regarding memory leaks, like you mentioned. You can, however, release the memory yourself with this code:

```
Bitmap bmp;    // your existing Bitmap
bmp.recycle(); // Clears the bitmap from memory
bmp = null;    // Unset it to be sure

final boolean isRecycled = bmp.isRecycled(); // Can be run to check if the
                                             // Bitmap is cleared from memory
```

If you consistantly clear your Bitmaps this way, you can avoid memory leaks. Reference: http://android.okhelp.cz/delete-bitmap-android-example/

Comment: it is not recovering that memory. Still there is memory leak.

Comment: Can you add the Exception/error you are getting to the OP? Maybe there is something else wrong. Also you will have to recycle EVERY Bitmap in your application...

Comment: I have only one Bitmap in my application.

Comment: Then there is probably something else wrong. What Exception or Error are you getting (with stack trace please)?

Comment: I am not getting any Exception. If I will get any Exception my App will crash.

Comment: If you don't get any exception regarding Bitmap's and OutOfMemory it will probably not be a Bitmap problem.